# How to set automatic output format of all my tables in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, dplyr, knitr, r-markdown, kable

I am writing an Rmarkdown document with plenty of tables, and I want them in a decent format, e.g. kable. however I don't want to format them one by one. Is there any easy way to knit the document such that the output format of every table would be kable style?

For example, I have created the following data frame in `dplyr`

```
data2 %>% 
  group_by(uf) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), ) %>% arrange(desc(n))
```

And I just want that query to have a `kable` style automatically, avoiding giving a name to the query and avoiding the kable function over that name. Why do I want it like this? Because of my document has hundreds of these `dplyr` queries and I need a faster way to knit the document.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a sample of the source tables and what you would like the results to look like.

Comment: I have created several `df` by using `dplyr`, and I want them to being formatted with kable automatically.

`data2 %>% 
  group_by(uf) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), ) %>% arrange(desc(n))`

That's it. I just want that this simple query have the `kable` format avoiding extra code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by using the [`printr` package](https://yihui.org/printr/).

Answer (score -1):

Just write a function to do what you want.  For example,

```
mykable <- function(x) kable(x, digits = 2, format.args = list(big.mark = ","))
```

then use

```
mykable(df)
```

to format `df` using those options.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not an automatic solution because of I have hundreds of `df` in my document (created with `dplyr`) and that would imply that I have to name my queries hundreds of times. Actually I would have to do this an many times as tables in my document.